# $x^2-xy-2x+3y=11$. Find natural solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got this factorizing:

$(x-2)(x-y)=11-y$. And I'm stuck on it. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7):

Note that $(x-3)(x-y+1)=8$

This is obtained by factorising the highest order terms $x^2-xy=x(x-y)$ and looking for a factorisation $(x+a)(x-y+b)=c$

Comment: oh and just plugging in x's such that x-3 divides 8. And finding y.

Answer (score 3):

If you write this equation in the form
$$
x^2-(y+2)x+(3y-11)=0,
$$
you can use the quadratic formula to get $x$ in terms of $y$, then see what natural numbers you can plug in for $y$ which make $x$ natural as well.

Comment: so D=y^2+4y-7 and it's positive if y<-5 or y>1 and sqrt(D) also has to be an even integer. How do I look through all y's?

Comment: oh no i got that wrong